# Convert PDF file to RDL format - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report structure designed in PDF format.

The PDf file looks like below:

[image]

I have to design this report in report builder and have some database interactions with my SQL procedure. So before starting the designing, I would like to know if there is any possibility to convert this PDF file directly into SSRS/RDL format. Any help?!

Answer (score 3):

PDF is a static document, so it doesn't change.  An SSRS/RDL report is the exact opposite of that - it's a dynamic document that is designed to change.  The closest you could come would be to create a program that extracted the layout from the PDF and wrote it out to an SSRS/RDL format.  IMO, the work that would require would far out weigh the benefit unless you were working with a very large number of files.  Even then, you would have to review every one of them, add in the query(s), parameters, formatting and all the stuff that makes an SSRS/RDL report what they are.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the form as a background image and drop your data on top, but there a some complexities in rendering.  See eg [SQL Server Reporting Services and Working with Overlay Data](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Gogolowicz-Swanson-SSRS)

So it may be easier to just reproduce the form in the report design.